# What is the correct place to ask an open question related to programming?

Tags: discussion

I had a question about programming in Clojure that is very open and I don't know where to ask it because Stack Overflow is not for open questions.

Where should I go?

Answer (score 4):

There is no Stack Exchange site that I'm aware of where open-ended questions are allowed, for example, over at [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) they are explicitly disallowed - according to their page about [questions to avoid](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

### See also

- [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Answer (score 4):

Your local usergroup would be a good place. Seriously. Not meant to be snide.

Try these links to find one near your place

- http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Clojure+User+Groups
- http://clojure.meetup.com

Answer (score 1):

I've used the programming chat rooms for things like that.  Just to feel out opinions on things.

Comment: Still, lurk there long enough to know if it's acceptable before.